# Package Markup with Javascript component for use as template

Tags: javascript, templates

I've got an HTML document `template.html` which looks something like:

```
<div id="Foo">
    <span class="Bar"></span>
    ...
</div>
```

Which I use as a template to construct some DOM for a component in Javascript.

At first, I just added it to my page `example.html` by copy-pasting the markup and wrapping it inside of a `<template>` tag. Then in my Javascript I constructed a clone to add it to the page by doing something like:

```
var myTemplate = Document.getElementById('#myTemplateId').cloneNode(true);
Document.getElementById('#newParent').appendChild(myTemplate, true);
```

While this works, I obviously don't want to have to copy and paste my templates over to be able to use my component.

What I would like to do is somehow package my template markup in with my Javascript. I still want to keep my Javascript and Markup separate for development and sanity, but at build time (I'm using GruntJS as my task runner) for the component I want to combine them somehow so they can be packaged in one, easy to link to file. What I mean by that is I want some way to package the template in with my Javascript, as Javascript. That said, I guess my broader question is:

**How can you save/package Markup into a Javascript file or object (JSON) so that it can be used as a template to generate DOM in Javascript later?**

The closest I have come to finding a potential solution was to convert the Markup document `template.html` to a string, save it to a variable, and then add it to a temporary element via `.innerHTML` and then convert it to make it a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). While that could work, there has to be a better way, and converting the Markup to a string doesn't feel right.

**Update:**

I know through my research that the trend of the industry is moving to [HTML imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/). However, it's [not widely supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=import), so in the meantime, I still want to be able to package my templates into my js.